# IV analysis for non-normal outcome distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, causality

I now have a set of data where the outcome is continuous count data but does not follow normal distribution. IV analysis relies on linear regression, in which normality is an important assumption. Can I use IV analysis with a non-normal outcome?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Although it may fit better at stats.stackexchange this is a common misconception especially among non-statisticians, so it could be helpful to have it here.

Answer (score 0):

In linear regression, the normality assumption is on the distribution of the error terms, not on the marginal distribution of the outcome (see ["Normality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Assumptions)).
This assumption is not strictly necessary but when it is met, the linear regression objective maximizes the likelihood of the sample, which leads to some nice properties.

In any case, a normally distributed outcome variable is not a requirement for a valid linear regression.